# Multiple errors when using video.currentTime

Tags: javascript

I am using this code to make a video player with custom controls. For some reason, I get an error telling me that my "seektimeupdate" and "vidseek" functions are not defined. I went into the console to see whether it will tell me where the error is but it doesn't tell me where.

```js
var myvideo = document.getElementById("myvideo")
var button = document.getElementById('button')
var seekslider = document.getElementById('vidtime');
var isplaying = false;
 function playvid() {
  if (isplaying==false) {
   myvideo.play();
   button.innerText="Pause"
   isplaying=true;
  } else {
   myvideo.pause();
      button.innerText="Play"
   isplaying=false;
  }
  function vidseek() {
   var seekto = myvideo.duration * (seekslider.value / 100);
   myvideo.currentTime = seekto;
  }
  function seektimeupdate() {
   var nt = myvideo.currentTime * (100 / myvideo.duration)
   seekslider.value=nt;
  }
  
 }
setInterval(seektimeupdate,10,false)
seekslider.addEventListener("change",vidseek,false)
```

```css
 body {
  background-color: #42b0f4;
 }
 #videocontrols {
  width:250px;
  background-color: #8c93a5;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: left;
 }
 #myvideo {
  align-self: center;
  background-color: #e2eaff;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 2px;
 }
 #vidtime {
  width: 100px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" id="myvideo"></video>
<div id="videocontrols">
<font color="#8c93a5">cv</font><button id="button" onclick="playvid()" height="25">Play</button><input type="range" id="vidtime" value="0" min="0" max="100">
</div>

</body>
```

If you look at my main code you can tell it's a bit messy, but what this is supposed to be doing is changing the time relative to the sliderbar and updating the bar every 10 milliseconds, instead I am just getting a big error. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had `vidseek()` and `seektimeupdate()` within `playvid()` function. Look at the code below:

```js
var myvideo = document.getElementById("myvideo")
var button = document.getElementById('button')
var seekslider = document.getElementById('vidtime');
var isplaying = false;
 function playvid() {
  if (isplaying==false) {
   myvideo.play();
   button.innerText="Pause"
   isplaying=true;
  } else {
   myvideo.pause();
      button.innerText="Play"
   isplaying=false;
  }
 }
    
    /* vidseek() and seektimeupdate() should live outside of playvid() function */ 
    function vidseek() {
   var seekto = myvideo.duration * (seekslider.value / 100);
   myvideo.currentTime = seekto;
 }
 
    function seektimeupdate() {
   var nt = myvideo.currentTime * (100 / myvideo.duration)
   seekslider.value=nt;
 }
setInterval(seektimeupdate,10,false)
seekslider.addEventListener("change",vidseek,false)
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #42b0f4;
 }
 #videocontrols {
  width:250px;
  background-color: #8c93a5;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: left;
 }
 #myvideo {
  align-self: center;
  background-color: #e2eaff;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 2px;
 }
 #vidtime {
  width: 100px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" id="myvideo"></video>
<div id="videocontrols">
<font color="#8c93a5">cv</font><button id="button" onclick="playvid()" height="25">Play</button><input type="range" id="vidtime" value="0" min="0" max="100">
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm such an idiot for not realising that! xD